# Error: expected ')' before 'ID'

Tags: c++, qt, while-loop

I'm writing client server program that server is multi thread, I want to use while() for creating loop in my thread , but it get the following error in myhthread.cpp:
"expected ')' before 'ID'"
I know my problem is basic but i am really confused about it... how can i create loop for it?Here is my code:

mythread.h

```
#ifndef MYTHREAD_H
#define MYTHREAD_H
#include <QThread>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTcpServer>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include "myserver.h"
#include <QDebug>

class mythread : public QThread
{
Q_OBJECT

public:

mythread(qintptr ID, QObject *parent) :

    QThread(parent)
{
    this->socketDescriptor = ID;
}

    void run()
    {
      qDebug() << " Thread started";

      socket = new QTcpSocket();

      if(!socket->setSocketDescriptor(this->socketDescriptor))
          {
              emit error(socket->error());
              return;
          }

//        if (m_client)


      connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readyRead()), Qt::DirectConnection);

      connect(socket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(disconnected()));


      qDebug() << socketDescriptor << " Client connected";

        exec();
    }

signals:

void error(QTcpSocket::SocketError socketerror);

public slots:

void readyRead();
void disconnected();

private:

QTcpSocket* socket;
qintptr socketDescriptor;

};

#endif
```

mythread.cpp:

```
#include "mythread.h"
#include "myserver.h"


mythread(qintptr ID, QObject *parent) :
{
   while(disconnected)
   {
      mythread::run();
   }
}

void mythread::readyRead()

{

QByteArray Data = socket->readAll();

qDebug()<< " Data in: " << Data;

socket->write(Data);
}


void mythread::disconnected()

{

qDebug() << " Disconnected";

socket->deleteLater();

exit(0);

}
```

Comment: even if offtopic, but it might also be that http://blog.qt.io/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/ fits for you. `QTcpSocket` is by default async, so why put it in a thread (you are doing it wront?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use scope resolution in the definition of your constructor in the cpp, and get rid of the `:` at the end of the line:

```
mythread::mythread(qintptr ID, QObject *parent) // :
{
    ...
}
```

Without the `mythread::` prefix,  the compiler understands that you want to declare some object of type `mythread` and is confused by the syntax.

**Edit:** as Danh noted, once you have corrected the error, the compiler will draw your attention that you have two definitions of the same constructor, which is illegal.

**Possible correction:** you should clean your class declaration in the header from all function implementation, and move implementation to the cpp file.  As you have two different implementations of the constructor, you could try to merge both :

```
//in the header:  no implementation of functions
class mythread : public QThread
{
    ...
    mythread(qintptr ID, QObject *parent); 
    void run(); 
    ...
 };

 // in the cpp
 mythread(qintptr ID, QObject *parent) 
     :  QThread(parent)
 {
    this->socketDescriptor = ID;
    while(disconnected)  // if you really want to do this during the construction
    {
       mythread::run();
    }
 }

 void mythread::run() 
 {
     ...
 }
```

Comment: Actually, he have defined 2  definition of `mythread::mythread(qintptr ID, QObject *parent)` I guess he will come back with new error.

Comment: @Danh good point !  Once the error is corrected, he'll get an explicit error message about a redefinition.

Comment: yes you guess right.. 
could you please tell me what should I do?

Comment: @Danh Oops  I was informed that your edit was rejected by my concurrent edition.  Unfortunately I can't find back in the history your suggestion to take it over.

Comment: My suggestion is nearly the same with you. Those bit difference are move `socketDescriptor` to initializer list, and I move the `while` loop in .ctor to `run` since in Qt, `QThread` will be initialized then we will call `QThread::start` to start a new thread, and `QThread::run` will be run inside that thread.

Comment: @Danh this is definitively the way to go !